# Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button vs Widget.AppCompat.Button

Tags: android, styles, android-appcompat

I´m Using `AppCompat 22.1.1`

What´s the difference between `Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button`and `Widget.AppCompat.Button` ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the case of `AppCompat.Button`, it inherits directly, and as far as I've been able to find, nothing overrides it, so they should be the same. From [`AppCompat styles.xml`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/v7/appcompat/res/values/styles.xml):

```
<style name="Widget.AppCompat.Button" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button" />
```

But according to the [AppCompat documentation](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support/+/master/v7/appcompat/THEMES.txt), we should be using `Widget.AppCompat`:

> Top level themes
>
> These are the themes to be used directly by developers. These inherit from
>   the relevant second level theme below.
>
> Names: `Theme.AppCompat`, `Theme.AppCompat.Light` and `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`
>
> Example: `values/Theme.AppCompat`    <-    `Theme.Base.AppCompat`

Comment: what is the use of appcompat button?

Comment: @Zapnologica If you're using AppCompat, it'll automatically use AppCompatButton when you use a normal button, and you only have to directly use that class when writing custom views. You normally encounter this while setting a style, so your button uses the Material Design style on old devices too. 

<Button 
...
style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless" />

There's tons of styles to play with in Widget.AppCompat.*